# React Material Ui Autofill Text input

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

i am using material UI and React for my project. i have several TextField and each of them has a button next to respectively, i want when a button was clicked, it will get the value of its TextField respectively and set the its value to the input of other TextField, here is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-frost-y79ru?file=/src/App.js:294-1144)

**Description**:

when you go to the link, you will have 3 TextField and 3 button next to each of TextField respectively,

```
 var defaultArray = Array(3).fill("");
 var [valueList, setValueList] = useState(defaultArray);
```

when you type the onChange event will set the respectively new value for item in array valueList but it will not update the defaultValue of the TextField, please make it update the defaultValue as well

```
 {valueList.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-basic"
              label="label"
              defaultValue={valueList[index]}
              onChange={(event) => {
                let newValueList = valueList;
                newValueList[index] = event.target.value;
                setValueList(newValueList);
                console.log(valueList);
              }}
            />
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => {
                let newValueList = Array(3).fill(valueList[index]);
                setValueList(newValueList);
                console.log(valueList);
              }}
            >
              Update All
            </Button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

thank you for taking time to help me out, if it is possible, you can modify it directly in the codesandbox link, have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the `index` of each array element to control the `value` of `TextField`. Make sure you clone your `valueList` in updating the state to avoid direct mutation of the array

```
<TextField
  id="standard-basic"
  label="label"
  defaultValue={valueList[index]}
  onChange={(event) => {
    let newValueList = [...valueList]; // <-- pay attention to usage of spread syntax
    newValueList[index] = event.target.value;
    setValueList(newValueList);
    console.log(valueList);
  }}
  value={valueList[index]} // <-- we can transform this to a controlled component
/>
```

[image: Edit blissful-morning-wbdj1]

Answer (score 0):

You already add the value on change in the array of valueList. Just get the value from that array and using the index and update that respectively. Please check the code below.

```
<Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => {
                let newValueList = valueList;
                newValueList[index] = valueList[index];
                setValueList(newValueList);
                console.log(newValueList);
              }}
            >
              Update All
            </Button>
```